# HAProxy not starting at boot

Tags: haproxy, centos7, systemd

I`ve installed and configured HAProxy with keepalived in CentOS 7 properly, the load balancing is working properly except that HAProxy is not starting at boot, I must start it manually.

If I run the command

```
systemctl is-enabled haproxy
```

It says that is enabled. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the output of `systemctl start haproxy`? Sometimes it's an selinux issue.

Comment: I`ve got this message from the log:
`Oct 15 10:46:48 CentOS7-HAProxy systemd: Starting HAProxy Load Balancer...
Oct 15 10:46:48 CentOS7-HAProxy systemd: Started HAProxy Load Balancer.`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. 
In my case it was because the directory `/run/haproxy` wasn't mounted automatically. So, I edited the file `/etc/init.d/haproxy`.
On the beginning of `start()` method i put:

```
if [ ! -d "/run/haproxy" ]; then
mkdir /run/haproxy
fi
```

And worked fine for me.